# What are Steps to grab the samples from AndEngine Repository

Tags: android, andengine

[image: I got the following error message]

I had tried to grab the samples of AndEngine using Mercurial eclipse plugins, but that was firing some sort of error to me again and again. So, can someone please let me know what could be the easiest way to get the AndEngine examples or samples from the repository. I am working on Windows.
Thanks.

Comment: It was like not able to execute hg.exe.So, I uninstalled and tried again but not got any progress. Is there anyother way we can grab the samples.

Comment: And I did that with EclipseHG only than to it was firing me some sort of errors, so what settings we have to do in the preferences?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***Update:***

[image: Eclipse preferences for mercurial]

Change the Mercurial client from the built in one to TortoiseHG (in the Eclipse preferences).

---

***Previous Answer:***

**Plan A:** Make sure to use native Mercurial with EclipseHG (not the one which ships with the plugin). You can find the settings the preferences dialog. Last time I tried, the built-in version was broken. If it fails again, copy and paste the error message.

**Plan B:** Try [TortoiseHG](http://tortoisehg.bitbucket.io/)

**Plan C:** Give us a concrete error message. (Which should actually be Plan A ;) )

Comment: You can give me the link and steps to do this because I did it several times and got error messages.

Answer (score 2):

You download the zip from https://github.com/nicolasgramlich/AndEngineExamples